# How to order by latest updated date between two date fields from different tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have two tables CUSTOMERS and QUERIES.. I want to display the result such that if new customer is added to CUSTOMER table or new query is added to QUERY table then which one is added recently among them should be ordered first..
I have tried query like this,

```
SELECT c.name, q.query FROM CUSTOMER c, QUERY q 
WHERE c.id=q.cust_id 
ORDER BY c.added_date DESC, q.added_date DESC;
```

But it is not showing proper result.. Plz help..

Comment: Why do you have Oracle tag along with MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the following:

```
order by greatest(c.added_date,q.added_date) desc
```

This works in postgres and other DBMSs - hopefully works the same for mysql and oracle.